# Unix - How to append text to every line of a file except for the header line/first line

Tags: sed

I have a file say abc.txt with following data (real data has many records,say around 200)

> Sno | Name
>   1 | Jack
>   2 | Jill
>   3 | June

Now how do I append text to make my file look like this,

> Sno | Name | Place
>   1 | Jack | Paris
>   2 | Jill | Paris
>   3 | June | Paris

I tried replacing globally ,but first line should be appended with different text.So please help me out guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are three options:

- awk and its variants (`gawk`, `mawk` etc.):

  ```
  awk '{if(NR==1){print $0,"| Place"} else{print $0,"| Paris"}}' file.txt
  ```
- Perl:

  ```
  perl -lne '$.==1 ? print "$_ | Place" : print "$_ | Paris"' file.txt
  ```
- sed

  ```
  sed '1 s/$/ | Place/; 1! s/$/ | Paris/' file.txt
  ```

Comment: Note that it's not only `gawk` or `mawk`, it's any `awk` implementation, POSIX ones, and even the original `awk` from 1981

Comment: @StephaneChazelas fair enough, that's why following your edit I used `awk` in the example and `(g/m)awk` in the header. Thanks.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas why is `1!` better than `2,$`? Is it just because it is shorter or is there a difference in the implementation?

Comment: IMO, shorter and easier to understand: you want the first substitution on the first line, and the second substitution on anything but the first line. Feel free to revert. I agree that edit was a bit cavalier, sorry.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas not cavalier, the day you make a _mistaken_ correction I will be (extremely) happy to point it out, till then I am just trying to learn and begin with the assumption that you're right. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

For scripted "in-place" file editing, use `ex`:

```
printf '%s\n' '1s/$/ | Place/' '2,$s/$/ | Paris/' x | ex abc.txt
```

- `printf` gives the commands to `ex`.
- `1s` performs the substitute on the first line only.
- `2,$s` performs the substitution on all other lines.
- `x` saves and exits.

The `$` in the regex means "end of line."